# Perform a series of operations on a vector in R without a loop

Tags: r, tidyr

I've got a vector that I want to perform the same operation on multiple times in series, modifying one argument, and I can't figure out a way to do it without a loop.

For example, say I want to take the vector `c(1, 2, 3)` and I want to perform a series of `logs` on it. In a loop, I would do this:

```
foo <- 30:32
for(anum in c(2,3,4)){
  foo <- log(foo, base = anum)
}
```

A way to do it without a loop would be:

```
30:32 |>
  log(base = 2) |>
  log(base = 3) |>
  log(base = 4)
```

What I'm wanting is to have a function that will take `2:4` as an argument and do this. So something like:

`30:32 |> serialfunction(log, 2:4)`

Does a function like this exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a built-in function that does exactly that. But you can do this with `Reduce`. For example

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {log(x, base=y)}, 2:4, init=30:32)
# [1] 0.2669627 0.2713007 0.2754373
```

You could create serial function with

```
serialfunction <- function(x, fun, y) {
   Reduce(function(x, y) {fun(x, y)}, y, init=x)
}
30:32 |> serialfunction(log, 2:4)
# [1] 0.2669627 0.2713007 0.2754373
```

Comment: Great answer. Of course, this _is_ doing it with a loop, but the loop is hidden in the body of the `Reduce` function. There has to be a loop _somewhere_ to achieve this.